# django reading text file to retrieve data

Tags: python, django, ioerror

I am facing strange problem. My django framework getting argument from template to retrieve data after reading text file. During testing it is doing perfect job. But when I am passing same argument from two browsers at same time I am getting following error for one of the browser:

```
IOError at /search/
[Errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

Although I know file is there and my python script can read it. So I am wondering anyone face this kind of problem in past!! What is the best way to handle file for retrieve data in Django.
Thanks

part of code of my django project

```
def search(request):
 if 'searchterm' in request.GET and request.GET['searchterm']:
    searchterm=request.GET['searchterm']
    searchtype= request.GET['searchtype']
    if len(searchterm)>0:
        pepfile = open(settings.BASE_DIR+'/filetoread/ReportBook_active_optimization.csv','r')
        contextres ={}
        concenrange={}
        for line in pepfile:
            data=line.strip()
            if not data.startswith('txtPeptideID'):
                info= data.split('\t')
                acclist=[]

                if searchtype =='Protein' and (str(searchterm)).lower() in info[2].lower():

                    for items in info[2].split('|'):
                        if (str(searchterm)).lower() in (items.strip()).lower():
                            itemsindex=(info[2].split('|')).index(items)
                            acclist.append((info[3].split('|'))[itemsindex])

                            transcountag6490=0
                            transpath=settings.BASE_DIR+'/tranisitionfilestoread'
                            curr_dir = os.getcwd()
                            os.chdir(transpath)

                            with open('transitions_6490_Agilent.csv', 'r') as transcountag6490file:
                                for line in transcountag6490file:
                                    if str(pepid) in line:
                                        transcountag6490=1
                                    else:
                                        transcountag6490=0
                            transcountag6490file.close()



        return render(request, 'resultform.html',  {'contextresultinfo': contextres, 'query': searchterm})
    else:
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'error': True})
else:
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'error': True})
```

Full trace of error:

```
IOError at /search/

[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'transitions_6490_Agilent.csv'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http:/127.0.0.1:8000/:8000/search/?searchtype=Any&     searchterm=PEP2012090602
Django Version:     1.8.11
Exception Type:     IOError
Exception Value:    

[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'transitions_6490_Agilent.csv'

Exception Location:     /home/paul/Desktop/djangoproject/trackerdatabase/src/trackerapp/views.py in search, line 188
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.6
Python Path:    

['/home/paul/Desktop/djangoproject/trackerdatabase/src',
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-20.3.1-py2.7.egg',
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-8.1.1-py2.7.egg',
'/usr/lib/python2.7',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']
```

Comment: This is really specific to your implementation. You need to share your code, otherwise you didn't give enough information so other people could help you.

Comment: I have shared code part of my project

Comment: you define a wrong path for a file/directory in your code somewhere. can you show the full error stack trace?

Comment: Added full error stack trace

Comment: your directory name in code is `tranisitionfilestoread` (extra i) - does it correspond to the actual directory name? also, try to open the `.csv` file using the abs path directly, without preventive `chdir`. try smth like `file_path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'tranisitionfilestoread', 'csv_file_name.csv')`

Comment: @iulian Thanks for your advice and it works now perfectly and many thanks for pointing out spelling mistake in directory name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll leave it here as an answer for easier finding by other SO members.

You don't need to make `os.chdir`, just provide the whole path to the file directly to `open()` call.

```
file_path = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'tranisitionfilestoread', 'transitions_6490_Agilent.csv')
with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
    # do stuff
```